# Xquery to concatenate

Tags: xquery

for the below data -

```
let $x := "Yahooooo !!!! Select one number - "
let $y := 
<A>
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>3</a>
  <a>4</a>
  <a>5</a>
  <a>6</a>
  <a>7</a>
</A>
```

I want to get the output as -

```
`Yahooooo !!!! Select one number - [1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7]`
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In XQuery 3.0, you can use [`||` as a string concatenation operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#doc-xquery30-StringConcatExpr):

```
return $x || "[" || fn:string-join($y/a, " or ") || "]"
```

In XQuery 1.0, you need to use [`fn:concat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat):

```
return fn:concat($x, fn:concat("[", fn:concat(fn:string-join($y/a, " or "), "]")))
```

Comment: you can try this solution here: http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/6vZl50qj2vDtRAB%2BPBTSFMEN2Ds%3D